Post Navigation Elementor
I'm using Elementor and ACF on a website and have a custom post type for events. In elementor I have the posts on the archive page set to order by the ACF start date field. When the user clicks the event and goes to the single event page there is a post navigation widget I'm using to move between posts. The issue is, the posts come up in menu order in the navigation instead of by the ACF field date.
I'd like the previous and next post links to be based on the ACF date field so when the user clicks either they are taken to the actual next post by date.
I just need a function to change the behavior of the widget in elementor which is the default wordpress settings.
I read the wordpress codex but it wasn't that helpful
My theme is a child them of Hello Elementor
